# How to detect if your Microsoft Access application is compiled, i.e. running as an ACCDE

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

Does anyone have any VBA to detect if your Microsoft Access 2013/2016 application is running as an ACCDE, i.e. is compiled?

I would like my code to stop and break if an error happens and a) it's me running it (environ("username')) and if it's not an ACCDE.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adapted from https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=229474 and http://allenbrowne.com/ser-53.html

```vb
Public Function IsACCDE() As Boolean

    ' Init
    IsACCDE = False

    ' This property exists only in compiled DBs (.mde, .accde)!
    ' Ignore error (and stay "False") if not.
    On Error Resume Next
    IsACCDE = (CurrentDb.Properties("MDE") = "T")

End Function
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for, works a treat. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't sure where that option was, but I found it.

Answer (score 0):

I use this which is part of Access VBA:

```
If IsCompiled = False Then
        DoCmd.RunCommand (acCmdCompileAndSaveAllModules)
End If
```

Comment: This answers a different question. `IsCompiled` will always be true in an .accde, it can be false only in an .accdb

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any properties that consistently gave me the correct answer. Then I realized that those approaches were all approximations to what I really wanted to know. Now I just ask directly if it is an accde.

```
Private Function InDevelopment() As Boolean

On Error Resume Next

    InDevelopment = False
    InDevelopment = (InStr(CurrentDb.Properties("Name"), "accde") = 0)
End Function
```

Comment: An `*.accdb` which has been renamed to `*.accde` isn't really a `accde`. So this way could return a wrong answer. Maybe the fact that an accdb can simply be renamed to accde caused that @Andre s answer didn't give you the 'correct' answer?

Comment: @UnhandledException That's an interesting point that I hadn't considered. I'm not coming up with a scenario where someone with access to the accdb would purposely disguise it as a de, so not clear how much effort to put into detecting it.

Comment: @UnhandledException What caused my issue was ignorance on my part. When you save the db as a de, it restarts. I thought it was starting the de copy. But it isn't. It restarts the db, but without the shift key, so it looked to me like the runtime version. My guess is that it was probably giving the correct answers, but I haven't been back to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot of things that depend on knowning if I am in DEV (accdb/mdb)  or LIVE  (accde/mde).

My method is to take  the right most letter.

```
strFinalDir = Right$(Application.CurrentProject.Name, 1)
```

Now I use B or E. The rest is easy.

But this is not the optimal solution as a hacker can physically change the last letter of the database.
This would make my code do "different" things and potentially expose my DB.

I've tried `If IsCompiled = False Then`, but this did not work for me.

So as of now, I am still using
`strFinalDir = Right$(Application.CurrentProject.Name, 1)`
and hoping a hacker does not know to change my e to b.

Comment: Why not use `CurrentDb.Properties("MDE")` ?